# Can Occam's razor be used in favor of scientific arguments against philosophical arguments?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, occams-razor

*Occam’s razor is a principle often attributed to 14th–century friar William of Ockham that says that if you have two competing ideas to explain the same phenomenon, you should prefer the simpler one.*

https://www.newscientist.com/definition/occams-razor/

So why do philosophers debate scientific arguments for any specific phenomenon (which are disproven , confirmed or validated with scientific tools and methods) by dismissing or downgrading the scientific evidence in general?

Examples related with my question may be the Berkeley's argument against Newtonian gravity, David Lewis's "New Work for a Theory of Universals" and other metaphysical and / or naturalistic justifications.

Comment: But usually science is not "simple" at all; see e.g. Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's an extreme example. Science is   usually  more simple

Comment: Please, provide some real example regarding "philosophers debating scientific arguments by dismissing or downgrading scientific evidence".

Comment: Having said that, so-called [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) is a generic "common sense" principle that hardly will be used in real life scientific research.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you can assume all of the philosophical arguments.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  This principle can be used to quickly find answers in many areas of life, both scientific and ordinary.

Comment: so for the example: "divine creator" vs "darwinian evolution" where/how are they "competing" (indeed)? (i think they perfectly fit and darwin far from atheist) ..and what is "simpler" to "whom"??? ;) (i think in historics/laws/archeology/forensics/criminology... this is still a valuable and practiced principle...)

Comment: @Wiseman To refer to "all of the philosophical arguments" is not helpful when asked for one concrete example. - One cannot answer your question as long as the premiss in your last sentence remains unclear.

Comment: @JoWehler you can think about any pheneomenon that includes a philosophical approach.

Comment: @Wiseman It looks as if you are sidestepping.

Comment: @JoWehler the question is asked in general. You may answer with your own examples.

Comment: @Wiseman scientific tools cannot prove **anything** (Popper showed you can't prove anything - Quine-Duhem that you can't unequivocally falsify anything).   Science is about reduction to the best explanation, not proof.  Proof is for mathematics, typesetting and alcohol,

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "Occam's razor ... hardly will be used in real life scientific research" - excuse me? I'd suggest reading [your own link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor#Uses): "In science, Occam's razor is used as a heuristic to guide scientists ... parsimony was an important heuristic in Albert Einstein's formulation of special relativity in the development and application of the principle of least action ..., and in the development of quantum mechanics ... In chemistry, Occam's razor is often an important heuristic ...".

Comment: @DikranMarsupScience relies on evidence. Evidence supports hypıthesis.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Excuse you! if you are trying to figure out why your car won’t start, you might start by examining the simplest and most obvious explanations, such as a dead battery or a loose wire. If these explanations don’t work, you can move on to more complex explanations, such as a faulty starter or alternator. Thats how Occam's Razors works in real life.

Comment: I was unaware that philosophers weigh in on scientific issues.  "What is light?" and "How do neutrinos behave in situation X?" are scientific issues.   "What is the line of demarcation between science and pseudoscience?" and "How should we conduct ourselves" are philosophical ones.   The idea that science and philosophy compete with each other is largely mythical.  //  If you disagree, and still insist that the two fields are trying to achieve the same goals, you will need to back up your claim with examples.   It's up to the guy who makes a claim to back it up with examples.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann ıt would be a good answer instead of comment. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Philosophy can help establish or support why we can or should trust science, while also providing some insights into the limits of science. This is the philosophy of science, and science did ultimately originate from philosophy.

However, this is not to say that some people don't misuse philosophy to try to argue against claims that are well-supported by science, or to argue for claims that science has disproven or failed to establish, or unreasonably criticise the reliability of science to try to support their desired conclusion, which is only supported by a highly unreliable method of gaining knowledge, if it's supported at all.

So Occam's razor can't universally be used to argue in favour of science above philosophy, but it is an important idea that could be used to argue against some claims (especially ones that are contrary to conclusions reached through science). If someone's making a philosophical argument, there could be many potential problems with it (or potentially no problems), so that will need to be handled on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Best answer for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems to boiled down to this- shouldn't philosophers be more rigorous in applying Ocram's, sorry, Occam's razor to cut the amount of time they spend in metaphysical speculations about matters well-explained by science? There are  at least three possible reasons why your expectations might not be fulfilled. Firstly, some philosophers (myself included) have reached such an advanced age that they simply forget O's r in the same way as they forget other everyday matters, such as their name, where they left the front door key, and so on. Then there are the young philosophers, green, impetuous, combative, thrusting, fizzling with ideas and opinions, too self-obsessed to consider the possibility that the three hundred and ninety eight page paper they have crafted about the meaning of time is mainly nonsense. For them, Occam is like a temperance advocate at a stag party. Thirdly, and more seriously, Occam's razor is not the ultra-decisive tool you imagine it to be, but one of the most mis-understood and mis-applied ideas in all of philosophy. Let's take solipsism, a subject I know to be dear to your heart. I am quite convinced that somewhere on this planet you will find a philosopher happily arguing that solipsism is the only outlook fully in accordance with Occam's razor, since it eliminates the billions of conscious entities assumed by the non-solipsist. Or take the many world's interpretation of quantum theory- perhaps the most ontologically extravagant idea ever conceived- there are people who say it is supported by Occam's razor because it avoids the collapse of the wave function. The point is that people can, and do, invoke Occam's grooming tool to support whatever bloated proposition they want to make.

Comment: Thank you. Good answer. You underlined my point of view whereas some philosopher and thinkers do very loopy and tautologic arguments that nobody easily can understand.

Answer (score 1):

The article that you cite makes the important caveat that a simpler explanation is not always to be preferred. The example given is the origin of life on Earth. Positing the existence of God is simpler than all that messy, complicated stuff involving chemistry and biology. On the other hand, theism is more complicated than atheism in that it involves metaphysics. However, I prefer the overarching Principle of Parsimony. The "turtles all the way down" joke illustrates the preference of philosophy against unnecessary complexity. My view is that underlying simplicity is often revealed by a thorough analysis of complexity. The trick is knowing when to apply the razor.

Comment: It would not be particularly reasonable to interpret "simple" to be strictly about initial number of entities, otherwise this would naturally tend towards entities of functionally infinite complexity (which some people indeed propose). In effect, this is just shifting complexity from number of entities to complexity of entities. Simplicity should involve considerations such as: what other claims would be entailed, how much of it is supported by evidence, and what else can a claim arbitrarily support (an all-powerful deity can support *any* existence, whereas evolution is much more specific).

Comment: `Positing the existence of God is simpler than all that messy, complicated stuff involving chemistry and biology` -- perhaps if you measure 'simplicity' in 'number of words', but scientists are more prone to measure 'simplicity' in 'bits of information required to create a simulation of a model'. Number of Words should *never* be confused with the type of simplicity Occam's Razor is talking about.

Comment: The razor is a tool, not an argument. No idea what "number of words" has to do with reality. I prefer answers to muddled comments.